# angularjs call function in ng-reapet to formate date String

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to do something like that?
I get an timestamp from JSON request and want to get the dayname, but not the english one. So i need a function call that returns the translated dayname.

I imagine something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days">
  <p>{{getI18nDayname(day.timestamp)}}</p>
</div>
```

getI18nDayname returns the right dayname other language.

Comment: rather than just imagine it .... try it first before asking. Can also create  custom filter

Comment: charlietfl, i tried it, but nothin worked out ;-)

Comment: but what you should be showing is what you tried. There might be better ways but the function should have worked. The whole idea of this site is to show your attempts so you learn from them

Comment: ok. I understand your argument. I will give my very best at next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing like that, what about something along these lines:

```
<p>{{day.timestamp | i18n_format}}</p>
```

or better yet

```
<p ng-bind="day.timestamp | i18n_format"></p>
```

i18n_format could be defined like so:

```
angular.module('app').filter('i18n_format', function() {
    return function (date) {
        return "date is: " date;
    }
});
```

inside the method you can define the code to localize it accordingly.

Comment: build my function to convert the dayname into the filter. works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can call function from the respective controller.

You should also try using angular date filter, to format date.

Something like this

```
{{your date | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}
```

Based on your requirement.

Checkout this for the different date filters in angular

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I tried the date filter, but it returns english day names